# moving a new visible Column to the end of the grid table in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

In a `React` app with `ag-grid 28.1.1`, I'm trying to find a way to move a newly added Column (by selecting it from the Columns toolpanel) to the end of the grid table. Currently when adding a new Column (from Columns Toolpanel) it's being added in the table in alphabetical order (say I add **D**ate column: it's being displayed between **C**onsumed and **E**arned)

I've tried with moveColumn method attached to onColumnVisible event but doesn't seem to work:

```
    onColumnVisible: ({ column, visible, columnApi }) => {
      const colId = column?.getColId();
      const lastIndex = columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns()?.length;
      if (colId && visible) {
        columnApi.moveColumn(colId, lastIndex);
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onColumnVisible: ({ column, visible, columnApi, api }) => {
  const colId = column?.getColId();
  const lastIndex = columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns()?.length;
  if (colId && visible) {
    api.moveColumn(colId, lastIndex);
  }
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).